# Coordinate of a Point Inside a Triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

> Coordinates to my triangle are $A(-1,10)$, $B(-7,1)$, $C(5,2)$ 
>   using trigonometry I can find the distance between $A-B$, $B-C$, and $C-A$. 
>   There is a point inside this triangle which is $7$ units from point $A$, $5.5$ units from $B$ and $9$ units from $C$. How do I find this point?

Comment: BTW It seems there is no such point. Can you check the numbers?

Comment: I have plotted a physical graph and there could be a slight variation in decimals, how were you able to tell that there is no such point what methodology you have used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the point you want to locate be $P(x,y)$, then you have been given the distances $PA, PB$ and $PC$ as $7, 5.5$ and $9$ respectively. So
\begin{align*}
PA^2&=(x+1)^2+(y-10)^2=7^2\\
PB^2&=(x+7)^2+(y-1)^2=(5.5)^2\\
PC^2&=(x-5)^2+(y-2)^2=9^2
\end{align*}
From these equations you can get (by subtraction etc.) two linear equations in $x$ and $y$. If they have a solution, then you get your point $P$, otherwise the point doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

> There is a point inside this triangle which is $7$ units from point
>   $A$, $5.5$ units from $B$ and $9$ units from $C$. How do I find this
>   point?

Hint: All points which are $7$ units away from point $A$ form a $\dotsc$ with $\dotsc$ $=7$.

Comment: not able to understand "form a .... with ... =7"

Comment: yea thats the problem i am not able to understand how to go about, sorry for being dumb

Comment: can you share your email ID, I can share an online graph with you to explain what I am doing, the issue is I am trying to find a specific point on the graph which will reside inside this triangle

Comment: That i understood that each of these individual distances basically represent a circle/arc of the radius that I had given you, but how willl it help in determining the coordinate of intersection of these circles?

Comment: yes they intersect at 2 points now

Comment: These two intersection points are part of two circles, they fulfill the distance condition of each of the two circles already. Your sought for point within the triangle does need to fulfill how many properties?

Comment: One distance each from point A and point B and angle it generates from point A and point B

Comment: Your special point needs to fulfill three distance conditions. Each distance condition can be characterized by a circle. You have drawn two so far.

Comment: I drew all the three circles they are interjecting at exactly one point ONLY, now the issue is how do I find this coordinate using an equation or a method where I dont have to draw circles

Comment: That is the point you are looking for. With the numbers you gave, you will get no such single point of intersection of three circles. The method is called trilateration.